# MSDeploy setParameter.xml not transforming web.config

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

In my "myconfig" config profile transform for web.config i have this under appSettings:

```
<add key="my.config" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" value="derp" />
```

When I msbuild with this transform the value is transformed correctly. Now I want to build an msdeploy package and transform this value at deploy time.

I drop this parameters.xml in my project root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters>
    <parameter name="my.config" description="sdfsdfsdfsd" defaultValue="fart">
        <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile"
                        scope="\\Web\.config$"
                        match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@my.config]/@value/text()" />
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

I build my package

```
msbuild app.csproj /T:Package /p:Configuration=myconfigprofile;PackageLocation=mydeploy.zip
```

I look at mydeploy.SetParameters.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<parameters>

  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/myApp_deploy" />
  <setParameter name="my.config" value="fart" />

</parameters>
```

Then I go into parameters.xml inside of mydeploy.zip and see its there too:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="my.config" description="sdkflsdjfldfj" defaultValue="fart">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\Web\.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@name='my.config']/@value/text()" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

looks good so far, then i deploy:

```
mydeploy.deploy.cmd /Y /M:server1
```

I look at web.config on the deploy server and the value is not transformed. I see no errors either, how do i debug this even?

When I run msbuild with parameters.xml present what magic happens there? How is the package preps to be able to transform web.config via parameters to web deploy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
add[@name='my.config']
```

Had to be changed to this:

```
add[@key='my.config']
```

But the bigger question remains, how do I debug?  I had to try a million times and just guess because I had zero errors/logs to help troubleshoot this. Is there verbose logging or some kind of validator or anything at all?

For debugging technet gave me this to try:
msbuild MyProject.proj /t:go /fl /flp:logfile=MyProjectOutput.log;verbosity=diagnostic

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MSDeploy you can get the full output of the deployment by using the following:

msdeploy -verb:sync -source:dirpath=C:\WebDeployDemo\Src -dest:dirpath=C:\WebDeployDemo\Dst -setParamFile=C:\WebDeployDemo\ParameterFile.xml -verbose >msdeploysync-verbose.log

This helps with VSTS WebRM deployment debugging if you use the -verbose flag.

Sources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-web-deploy
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2012/10/12/using-msdeploy-to-update-and-remove-sections-in-web-config-a-simple-example/